# ¿Cómo eliminar archivos de un directorio de mi servidor Node?

Tags: nodejs, video, fs, eliminar

Tengo un flujo de de trabajo corriendo en un servidor de Node, esto realiza básicamente:

1. Llamado a la API de Zoom para obtener todas las reuniones
2. Consulta a la base de datos para obtener todas las asignaturas y su directorio en Google Drive
3. Comienzo de un bucle para descargar todas las grabaciones que se encuentren disponibles
4. Descarga del archivo
5. Subida del archivo MP4 a la carpeta de Google Drive
6. Petición a la API de Zoom para eliminar el archivo descargado
7. (Eliminación del archivo local en el servidor)

El punto número 7 es el que me falta integrar, se debe hacer con el modulo fs pero no recuerdo como, si alguien me pudiera dar la respuesta estaría agradecido. Intente buscar, pero no dispongo de mucho tiempo y por eso realice la pregunta.

El directorio desde donde quiero eliminar es /files/(nombredelarchivo).mp4 en la raiz está el index.js que es la raiz del servidor.

Actualmente los estoy borrando de forma manual, pero debo automatizarlo.

Como dato, no debo verificar si el archivo existe o no, ya que, se debería borrar despues de subirlo a  Google Drive, por lo cual, si se sube se borra. Siguiendo el flujo.

Estuve leyendo la documentación del modulo FS, mientras encuentro a alguien que me pueda ayudar.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como es que estás subiendo los archivos a google drive ?.

Si es mediante un for, te recomiendo subirlo y luego eliminarlo con FS

```
const fs = require('fs')

const path = './file.txt'

try {
  fs.unlinkSync(path)
  //file removed
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Si tienes los path en un array, te recomiendo recorrerlos y llamar a dicho código, ya que no es posible pasarle un array con paths al fs unlink.

Éxito.

Comment: Exacto estoy recorriendo el arreglo de grababaciones, pero almaceno el nombre del archivo actual del ciclo en una variable por lo que para eliminarlo solo necesito entregarle esa variable, no tengo la necesidad de recorrer el arreglo nuevamente. Queria saber si es necesario agregar la extensión del archivo, en el  ejemplo que yo vi no salía con extensión pero de igual manera lo elimina. ¿Recomiendas usar la extensión?

Comment: A todo esto, luego quiero actualizar a una estructura de datos de tipo cola, para evitar errores y que se trabaje archivo por archivo. Pero por motivos de urgencia trabajo con estructuras de datos del lenguaje.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar la extensión, así tienes una diferencia de archivos y nombres más certera. Saludos. Me comentas si te ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución con el modulo FS, he usado destructuring para acceder a `unlink  const {unlink} from 'fs/promises`. Luego se debe ejecutar dentro de un try catch o alguna funcion asyncrona: `await unlink('/directorio')` y el archivo se elimina correctamente.